# How to make a bill by Python

Tags: python, billing

I'm a freshman, and I want to make a bill that write out what I bought, quantity and how much total cash it cost.

```
customer = str(input("Customer's name: "))
print ("Welcome to our store")
print ("This is our products")
print ("orange 0.5$)
print ("Apple 1$)
print ("Grape 0.5$)
print ("Banana 0.5$)
chooseproducts= int(input("What do you want to buy: "))

For output example. Can you guys help me please. 
    

         BILL
Orange     5    2.5$
Apple      3    3$
Grape      2    1$
Total:     10   6.5$
```

Comment: if you are new to python then you will need to learn many things before you can understand and make the output you want. I would recommend you to first learn the basics and then try making these small projects. Because if you don't learn the basics and just gon on making the project you won't understand what you are doing and what's going wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i spend a whole day to deal with this problem and can't find a solution, so i post it up here, meanwhile i still find my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `str(input(customer's name: ))` code needs to be changed. `input()` calls need a string as the question, and also the apostrophe has Python think that it is the start of a string.
Also, when you are printing the costs, you need another closing quotation mark. When you are asking the user about what they want to buy, I suppose you want them to input the name of the fruit. Since you have the `int()` in the front, Python cannot turn a string like "orange" or "grape" into an integer. When people want to buy multiple things, however, they might only put one thing in.
I suppose that this isn't all your code, and you have the part where you calculate the cost. If I were to write this code, I would write it like the following:

```py
customer = str(input("Customer's Name:"))
print ("Welcome to our store")
print ("This is our products")
print ("Orange 0.5$")
print ("Apple 1$")
print ("Grape 0.5$")
print ("Banana 0.5$")
prices = {"orange":0.5,"apple":1,"grape":0.5,"banana":0.5}# I added this so we can access the prices later on
#chooseproducts= int(input("What do you want to buy: "))
# The code below this is what I added to calculate the cost.
productnum = input("How many things do you want to buy: ") # This is for finding the number of different fruits the buyer wants
while not productnum.isdigit():
    productnum = input("How many different products do you want to buy: ")
productnum = int(productnum)
totalprice = 0
totalfruit = 0
print('         BILL')
for i in range(productnum):
    chosenproduct = input("What do you want to buy: ").lower()
    while not chosenproduct in ['orange','apple','banana','grape']:
        chosenproduct = input("What do you want to buy: ").lower()
    fruitnum = input("How many of that do you want to buy: ")
    while not fruitnum.isdigit():
        fruitnum = input("How many of that do you want to buy: ")
    fruitnum = int(fruitnum)
    totalfruit += fruitnum
    price = fruitnum * prices[chosenproduct]
    totalprice += price
    startspaces = ' ' * (11 - len(chosenproduct))
    endspaces = ' ' * (5 - len(str(fruitnum)))
    print(chosenproduct.capitalize() + startspaces + str(fruitnum) + endspaces + str(price) + '$')

print('Total:     ' + str(totalfruit) + ' ' * (5 - len(str(totalprice))) + str(totalprice) + '$')
```

Please make sure you understand the code before copying it, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much sir, i wil analyze this and change it a little bit for my purpose, and i have to say it again, thank you so much.